# Should I go for a Campus or University

Tags: university

I'm currently looking at higher studies options, taking a degree in Computer Science. So far, I have two options:

- Get a degree locally, from a campus that partners with a foreign University and you get the same degree as the partner University students.
- Go abroad and get a degree directly.

What would be better? Would the first option be OK?

Comment: IMHO, I would go abroad because it would expose you to a different culture and broaden your experiences.

Comment: @MichaelC. That comes in with the exponentially higher costs for the degree.

Comment: Well then if cost is the main factor, then go to your local university.... not sure why you would ask which one is "better" or which one is "OK" if cost is involved...

Comment: @MichaelC. Just stating a con. It's not a local university I can attend, it's a campus. Local universities don't accept people from the exam boards I took my exams with. They only accept students who passed their local exam boards.

Comment: Then I would list out the pros and cons and go from there. Either way, your diploma is going to say "XYZ University".

Comment: @MichaelC. Would the employers still treat a graduate from a Campus and a graduate from the same University the Campus is affiliated with

Answer (score 1):

My university has three campuses. Two are very close together, in the same town in fact (about a 10 minute walk apart). Most of the main university buildings are on the larger of the two, with the smaller one containing a few department buildings (e.g. Law and Business) and another library. The third campus is halfway round the world in the Southern Hemisphere.

To the best of my knowledge, you can study for a degree on any of the three campuses and your degree will only state the name of the university, not the campus you studied on (which is only of administrative importance and not relevant to what you studied). You even state this yourself in your question:

> "...you get the same degree as the partner University students."

I would not worry about the value of the degree if studied for at a separate campus. The university itself should ensure that academic standards are maintained across all its campuses, including those abroad, as if they did not this would only devalue the degrees they offer.

Comment: "The university itself should ensure that academic standards are maintained across all its campuses" - and yet, so many don't.

Comment: Campus is not owned by them. It's a third party